# Is there a way to run rspec tests over and over?

Tags: ruby, windows, rspec

I want to run my `_spec.rb` test in a loop, but I can't find a way to do that.

I have tried to make a loop `.bat` file but it doesn't run spec file again after finishing :

```
:start 
rspec some_test_spec.rb 
sleep 30 
goto start
```

Mayby there is any better/ easier way to do that for example using `bundle exec rspec` or `rake` command?

Comment: Do you want to do this only for a particular spec, or for a bunch of different specs? Do you want to do it only when code changes, or regardless of whether code has changed?

Comment: For one spec and also for a brunch of different specs. I want to run it by hand every time i need it and loop can stop after failing or i can stop it by hand. I only need to repeat in a loop one command that will run spec file. So i thought that it is possible to create a simple loop but it doesn't work. 
I am using windows.

Comment: @Dave Schweisguth 
but it works like this. simple, but not the best solution.

:start 
start my_loop.bat
sleep 30 
goto start

**my_loop.bat** - has code to run spec files.

Comment: Well, that clarifies the problem. Can't help myself as I don't have a Windows handy, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

With [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec), you can run your rspec tests automatically once any of the watched files changed. This is often used during development e.g. when appying the Red/Green/Refactor style of TDD.